# Extract href parameter from <a> tag by using Mechanize and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <li>
        <h2>
            <a href="https://www.congress.gov/bill/99th-congress/senate-joint-resolution/427">S.J.Res.427</a>
        </h2>
    </li>
    <li>
        ....
    </li>
</div>
```

I want to extract the href value of the `<a>` tag.

Using Mechanize and Nokogiri I did this:

```
activity_list = member.search('#main li')
activity_list.each do |link| 
    activity_link = link.at("h2 a[href]")
end
```

but I got `TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String`

What's wrong?

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. On my machine the code above runs perfectly. You have an error probably induced by some other piece of code.

Comment: @mudasobwa hi, i have fixed it by changing it to activity_link = link.at('h2 a[href]').to_s . But still its not the result that I want, because it gave me the whole thing which is <a href="https://www.congress.gov/bill/99th-congress/senate-joint-resolution/427">S.J.Res.427</a> . While i just want the href value. How to delete other stuff and just extract the href value?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `#attr` method:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML('<div id="main"><li><h2>
  <a href="https://www.congress.gov/bill/99th-congress/senate-joint-resolution/427">S.J.Res.427</a>
</h2></li></div>')
html.search('#main li').each do |link|
  #                         ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
  puts link.at("h2 a[href]").attr('href')
end
#⇒ https://www.congress.gov/bill/99th-congress/senate-joint-resolution/427
```

Comment: or more commonly `#[]`

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
    <div id="main">
      <li>
        <h2>
          <a href="foo">S.J.Res.427</a>
        </h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2>
          <a href="bar">S.J.Res.427</a>
        </h2>
      </li>
    </div>
EOT

activity_list = doc.search('#main li')
activity_list.each do |link| 
  activity_link = link.at("h2 a[href]") 
  activity_link['href'] # => "foo", "bar"
end
```

When you are pointing to a node, you can use `[]` to access the values of parameters.